# How to put the average value into particular date?

Tags: r

I have a data set consist of the average value from particular date. Please see the example of dataset below:

```
structure(list(startdate = structure(c(14951, 14958, 14965, 14978, 
14985, 14992), class = "Date"), enddate = structure(c(14957, 
14964, 14971, 14985, 14992, 14999), class = "Date"), Conc = c(5.873, 
14.591, 8.854, NA, 20.228, 74.57)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to produce new data set consist of daily data based on above dataset. Please see the new dataset I desired below:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14951, 14952, 14953, 14954, 
14955, 14956, 14957, 14958, 14959, 14960, 14961, 14962, 14963, 
14964, 14965, 14966, 14967, 14968, 14969, 14970, 14971, 14972, 
14973, 14974, 14975, 14976, 14977, 14978, 14979, 14980, 14981, 
14982, 14983, 14984, 14985, 14986, 14987, 14988, 14989, 14990, 
14991, 14992, 14993, 14994, 14995, 14996, 14997, 14998), class = "Date"), 
    Conc = c(5.873, 5.873, 5.873, 5.873, 5.873, 5.873, 5.873, 
    14.591, 14.591, 14.591, 14.591, 14.591, 14.591, 14.591, 8.854, 
    8.854, 8.854, 8.854, 8.854, 8.854, 8.854, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.228, 20.228, 20.228, 
    20.228, 20.228, 20.228, 20.228, 74.57, 74.57, 74.57, 74.57, 
    74.57, 74.57, 74.57)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I can do the opposite (calculate the average value from particular date), but I don't have any idea how to do the opposite. I have  a big data set and if I can do this, it will save my life. Please anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first create a data.frame containing all days between the first `startdate` and the last `enddate`. Then we join the averages data.frame and group by each "section" of available values for `Conc`. Within each of these groups we check if the date is within `startdate` and `enddate` and if so replace the value with the first value for `Conc`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(startdate = seq(min(df1$startdate), max(df1$enddate), by=1)) %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>% 
  group_by(cumsum(!is.na(Conc))) %>% 
  mutate(Conc = ifelse(startdate <= first(enddate), first(Conc), NA)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Date = startdate, Conc)
```

Returns:

```
         Date   Conc
1  2010-12-08  5.873
2  2010-12-09  5.873
3  2010-12-10  5.873
4  2010-12-11  5.873
5  2010-12-12  5.873
6  2010-12-13  5.873
7  2010-12-14  5.873
8  2010-12-15 14.591
9  2010-12-16 14.591
10 2010-12-17 14.591
11 2010-12-18 14.591
12 2010-12-19 14.591
13 2010-12-20 14.591
14 2010-12-21 14.591
15 2010-12-22  8.854
16 2010-12-23  8.854
17 2010-12-24  8.854
18 2010-12-25  8.854
19 2010-12-26  8.854
20 2010-12-27  8.854
21 2010-12-28  8.854
22 2010-12-29     NA
23 2010-12-30     NA
24 2010-12-31     NA
25 2011-01-01     NA
26 2011-01-02     NA
27 2011-01-03     NA
28 2011-01-04     NA
29 2011-01-05     NA
30 2011-01-06     NA
31 2011-01-07     NA
32 2011-01-08     NA
33 2011-01-09     NA
34 2011-01-10     NA
35 2011-01-11 20.228
36 2011-01-12 20.228
37 2011-01-13 20.228
38 2011-01-14 20.228
39 2011-01-15 20.228
40 2011-01-16 20.228
41 2011-01-17 20.228
42 2011-01-18 74.570
43 2011-01-19 74.570
44 2011-01-20 74.570
45 2011-01-21 74.570
46 2011-01-22 74.570
47 2011-01-23 74.570
48 2011-01-24 74.570
49 2011-01-25 74.570
```

Note: It seems your expected output is missing the last value for 2011-01-25

Comment: Thank you both of you. I really appreciate your help. It save my life.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/) solution that leverages [`tidyr::separate_rows()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html) and string manipulation, without the need for any `join`ing or `group`ing.  However, for very long windows of time, where `startdate` and `enddate` are very far apart, this solution might prove computationally inefficient — or even strain memory limits — when attempting to cram each sequence of dates into a single string.

## Solution

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate your first dataframe 'dataset_1'.
# ...


results <- dataset_1 %>%
  # Create a 'Date' column, where each value is a string enumerating each day (as
  # an integer) between 'startdate' and 'enddate':
  #   "14951 14952 14953 14954 14955 14956 14957"
  #   "14958 14959 14960 14961 14962 14963 14964"
  #   ⋮
  rowwise() %>% mutate(Date = paste(startdate:enddate, collapse = " ")) %>%
  # Use 'tidyr::separate_rows()' to pivot each day into its own row.
  separate_rows(Date, sep = " ", convert = TRUE) %>%
  # Format each day as a 'Date' object.
  mutate(Date = structure(Date, class = "Date")) %>%
  # Format the dataset as desired.
  select(Date, Conc)


# View results.
print(results, n = Inf)
```

## Results

Given a `dataset_1` like the one you reproduced

```
dataset_1 <- structure(
  list(
    startdate = structure(
      c(14951, 14958, 14965, 14978, 14985, 14992),
      class = "Date"
    ),
    enddate = structure(
      c(14957, 14964, 14971, 14985, 14992, 14999),
      class = "Date"
    ), 
    Conc = c(5.873, 14.591, 8.854, NA, 20.228, 74.57)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

this solution should yield the following `results`:

```
# A tibble: 45 x 2
   Date        Conc
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2010-12-08  5.87
 2 2010-12-09  5.87
 3 2010-12-10  5.87
 4 2010-12-11  5.87
 5 2010-12-12  5.87
 6 2010-12-13  5.87
 7 2010-12-14  5.87
 8 2010-12-15 14.6 
 9 2010-12-16 14.6 
10 2010-12-17 14.6 
11 2010-12-18 14.6 
12 2010-12-19 14.6 
13 2010-12-20 14.6 
14 2010-12-21 14.6 
15 2010-12-22  8.85
16 2010-12-23  8.85
17 2010-12-24  8.85
18 2010-12-25  8.85
19 2010-12-26  8.85
20 2010-12-27  8.85
21 2010-12-28  8.85
22 2011-01-04 NA   
23 2011-01-05 NA   
24 2011-01-06 NA   
25 2011-01-07 NA   
26 2011-01-08 NA   
27 2011-01-09 NA   
28 2011-01-10 NA   
29 2011-01-11 NA   
30 2011-01-11 20.2 
31 2011-01-12 20.2 
32 2011-01-13 20.2 
33 2011-01-14 20.2 
34 2011-01-15 20.2 
35 2011-01-16 20.2 
36 2011-01-17 20.2 
37 2011-01-18 20.2 
38 2011-01-18 74.6 
39 2011-01-19 74.6 
40 2011-01-20 74.6 
41 2011-01-21 74.6 
42 2011-01-22 74.6 
43 2011-01-23 74.6 
44 2011-01-24 74.6 
45 2011-01-25 74.6
```